Why is the use of Artificial Intelligence allowed here? Should it be?
Every StackExchange site has a “What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools?” page.
Like many, SuperUser’s, for example, explicitly states that

Generative Artificial Intelligence tools may not be used.

They also announced it on their Meta.

But according to our page

Generative Artificial Intelligence tools can be used to generate content for Information Security Stack Exchange


This confuses me, because unofficially, it seems that AI answers are very much frowned upon.
Why are we allowing the use of such tools, unlike many sister sites?
Should we keep allowing them?

I actually don’t think this has been brought up before. But I could be wrong.

Browsing at the big list on Is there a list of ChatGPT or other AI-related discussions and policies for our sites?, looks like there wasn't any such discussion about it here, thus it got the default template for the help center.

GenAI answers can be used to generate content, but it needs to meet the standards of the site. And that's the sticking point.
Sometimes it appears that people dump the title question into ChatGPT and copy/paste the result into the Answer space with no regard for accuracy, context, or relevance. The fact that it is GenAI isn't the issue there. But rather the fact that there was so little regard for the question that the answer is suspect.
So, AI is fine, but it needs to meet a basic quality standard, and, as the link you provided explains, it needs to be cited so we understand what the source really is: the person's expertise, experience, and research, or a magic answer box.
So when people, or mods, suggest that an answer might be "AI-generated", the complaint is either about the quality, the lack of citation (therefore plagiarism), or the fact that the answer amounts to a google search link.
We could connect each question to the OpenAI API and have answers automatically generated, but that's of little value. The value of the community is the expertise and experience of the members to add their personal perspectives to the facts. And as long as that's happening alongside a generated answer, then that's similar to quoting an article and providing an explanation for how it applies to the question. And that's the model we should be using.

This is a great explanation. I saw the “needs referencing” part, but I’ve never actually seen anyone, ever, ‘admit’ to having their answer partially/fully AI generated. The people who get in trouble clearly don’t accredit the LM, either because they don’t know, or because they don’t want to for whatever reason(s). Have you ever seen a post that does cite to the apparent AI content.

And it seems likely that someone responsible enough to accredit the LM is responsible enough to not subject their answer to a level of low quality. Meaning that it’s probably more likely to be allowed.
I also wonder if people who don’t cite the AI usage are actually embarrassed about it. Because to me, in some ways, it shows a lack of understanding.

I have seen people try to cite ChatGPT, but only in the beginning as if they were trying to archive the answers. The results were pure rubbish and ended up getting deleted.

For me, the best way to use GenAI answers is if it is so good and so relevant, that the source almost doesn't matter.

I see. I’ll keep that in mind, this information should prove useful for community moderation.

My all-time personal favourite question here is when someone copy/pasted a response from ChatGPT and asked the community to vet the veracity of it. This was close to the beginning of ChatGPT's release. An interesting approach, almost as if we were training the LLM, but they didn't consider the long-term and holistic implications if we allowed such a question type. Can you imagine?

That is quite amusing, in fact. If we did allow such questions then we would have to read through many long, repetitive, and boring ChatGPT responses and then reply with “not only is this is incorrect, it’s irrelevant.”!
